# How to calculate distance or similarity between one item and an item set?

Tags: r, distance, similarity

All the dist/similarity functions in packages i have known are designed to calculate the distance/similarity of "every pair of rows" in the matrix.

If the input matrix is extremely large, the dist matrix will need much bigger memory since n rows of input matrix will lead to a n*n sized dist matrix.

I have a target item x and an item set Y, I want to calculate dist/similarity between this target item x and every item y in Y. How can i do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good place to use the apply function. What you want to do, is get a comparison between your target item, x, and each item of y. This can be done by applying a function across each item of y.

Assuming y is a matrix, and each column is an item, this is easy for correlation because it can calculate the correlation between two items:

```
apply(y, 2, cor, x)
```

This will give you a vector where each element corresponds to the correlation between x, and the i'th item of y.

You can also change the method of correlation if you wish:

```
apply(y, 2, cor, x, method="spearman")
```

This is a little more complicated if you're using dist because it doesn't take two arguments. Also it assumes that the rows are items instead of the columns:

```
apply(y, 2, function(y.item, x.item) { dist(rbind(y.item, x.item)) }, x)
```

Again, if you want to use a different method of distance than the default (or change other arguments to dist), you can always pass in more arguments:

```
apply(y, 2, function(y.item, x.item, ...) { 
    dist(rbind(y.item, x.item), ...) 
}, x, method="manhattan")
```

Comment: +1 - excellent explanation - I might add that the function `vegdist` from the `vegan` package allows for many other definitions of distance, and could be applied in the same manor as the last example.

Answer (score 0):

Problems can be solved with  proxy package

```
x<-rnorm(10)         
x<-matrix(x)                   
y<-matrix(rnorm(10*5),nrow=5)                
require( proxy)                     
dist(t(x),y)
```